# ChartJS v2: how to remove strange line in Line Chart

Tags: javascript, cordova, chart.js

I am working on a Cordova project and I use ChartJS v2 to display a Line chart. Everything is ok except for on strange line for points which has x value = 0. I tried many steps to change it to a straight line. But it is work in `jsfiddle` project with the same code.

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/742zut83/103/)

How I can restrict it or remove it to not go under the x-axis?

[image: Line Chart issue]

Answer (score 0):

I am using ChartJS version 2.1.6 and I found that it is seem a bug of ChartJS. This issue is reported at [here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2768)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the ChartJS v2.5.0 and it solves the issue. Maybe the ChartJS team has fixed that issue at this version.